Compilation of the function that should return vector along with matrix
I am looking for the way how to compile the function that is supposed to return vectors along with matrices. The simplified example looks next:
FunMixedReturn = Compile[{{X, _Real, 1}, {Y, _Real, 1}},

                    {X, Table[X[[i]]*Y[[j]], {i, 1, Length[X]}, {j, 1, Length[Y]}]},
      
                    CompilationTarget -> "C",
                    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
                    Parallelization -> True,
                    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
                  ]

After evaluation this function returns the right results
FunMixedReturn[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]

which is
{{1, 2, 3}, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}}}

but with the next warnings:


How correctly to write the compiled function that should return mixture of vectors and matrices? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Does this answer your question? How to force Compile to return multiple results? Also a warning: KroneckerProduct is not among the compilable functions, so you are not gaining any performance with compilation in this case.

@Domen I removed KroneckerProduct from the function. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try the workaround proposed in this answer
